# Use colour specification for TikZ arrow and label without first using `\definecolor`

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-cd

Consider the following, in which arrows and labels are coloured using `\definecolor`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{reddish}{HTML}{A01A3A}
\definecolor{blueish}{HTML}{196F9E}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \textcolor[HTML]{A01A3A}{P} & {Q}
    \arrow["f"'{color=blueish}, from=1-1, to=1-2, color=reddish]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

`definecolor` is not necessary for *vertex* labels: I can use a colour specification directly with `\textcolor`. How can I do the same for the label and body of an arrow? That is, I want to be able to remove the `\definecolor` declarations and declare the colour specifications inline. Ideally, I would be able to write something like:
`\arrow["f"'{color={\color[HTML]{196F9E}}}, from=1-1, to=1-2, color={\color[HTML]{A01A3A}}]`.

I'd be happy to define a new command, e.g. `\inlinecolor` that was compatible with `color` if there is no native TikZ syntax for this.

Comment: This syntax is not supported in tikz. You would have to define your own keys which first define the color. But why do you want this? Predefining the color makes the code much more readable.

Comment: The colours are one-off, so it would be a single definition for a single usage, which to me is less readable (it's certainly more verbose).

Comment: Why you not use predefined colors in options  `dvipsnames` or `svgnames` or `x11names`?

Comment: The colours are coming from an external source and may not match the existing colours in those lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xcolor` package has this weird syntax that I have never found useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{reddish}{HTML}{A01A3A}
\definecolor{blueish}{HTML}{196F9E}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \textcolor[HTML]{A01A3A}{P} & {Q}
    \arrow["f"'{color=blueish}, from=1-1, to=1-2, color=reddish]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \textcolor[HTML]{A01A3A}{P} & {Q}
    \arrow["f"'{color={rgb,256:red,26;green,111;blue,158}},
        from=1-1, to=1-2, color={rgb,256:red,160;green,26;blue,58}]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \textcolor[HTML]{A01A3A}{P} & {Q}
    \arrow["f"'{color={rgb,"100:red,"19;green,"6F;blue,"9E}},
        from=1-1, to=1-2, color={rgb,"100:red,"A0;green,"1A;blue,"3A}]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect. I see this is the *extended color expression* syntax of 2.3.3 in the `xcolor` documentation. One question: where is the `"100` syntax described? It's a little difficult to search for.

Comment: If a number is prefixed by `"` it is interpreted hexadecimally. This is a TeX feature, not a package one.

Comment: I had never encountered that before, thanks.

Comment: After double-checking with the xcolor doc I feel like `256` and `"100` should be replaced by `255` and `"FF`, for that FFFFFF should be completely white, not just 255/256 white.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, you can define keys that allow you to do that. (To which extent this is an incredibly useful key is for others to judge, but it is certainly less efforts to define the style than trying to argue why it may not be worthwhile. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
% \definecolor{reddish}{HTML}{A01A3A}
% \definecolor{blueish}{HTML}{196F9E}
\tikzset{html color/.code={\definecolor{html-#1}{HTML}{#1}%
\tikzset{color=html-#1}}}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \textcolor[HTML]{A01A3A}{P} & {Q}
    \arrow["f"'{html color=196F9E}, from=1-1, to=1-2, html color=A01A3A]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd rather not define a new key that serves the same purpose as `color`. However, defining a command to pass as the value of `color` seems reasonable, e.g. something like `\newcommand{\inlinecolor}[1]{\definecolor{color-#1}{HTML}{#1} color-#1}` (though this doesn't quite work). I'm slightly concerned that this could conflict with existing names in the namespace though: is there a way to unique generate a colour name that's guaranteed to be new?

Comment: @varkor These definitions are *local* so at most you overwrite a color *locally*, which is the arrow path in this case. And of course your command does not work, it is not what is often referred to as "expandable". When you say that you do not want to define a new key, the only alternative seems to be to redefine the `color` key. Possible, but not something I want to be involved with.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is it possible to make a macro like this expandable, or is the problem that macros won't be expanded in TikZ arguments at all?

Comment: @varkor This question concerns basically `\definecolor`. I did not check, but its name suggests that it contains `\def`, so it is not "expandable". Please note that the term "expandable" is, ironically, a bit "stretchable", so it depends on how you interpret the term, but I am pretty certain that an attempt to inject something along the lines of `\inlinecolor` into color commands will have to fail (unless you prepare the color commands for that).

Comment: Okay, thanks. It sounds like a new key is the best realistic solution, so I'm going to mark this as answering the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, this might have quite unexpected side-effects, because a TikZ path is an implicit TeX group, so the color definition on the TeX side disappears afters the path is finished, but objects are still written to the PS/PDF file.  I don't know whether this is much of a problem for colors but it sure would be for shadings.

Comment: @HenriMenke What you are saying is that if someone uses a shading in which they use a color that has the name `html-A01A3A`, say, but does not correspond to the color that one obtains with `\definecolor{html-A01A3A}{HTML}{A01A3A}`, and then in a local group one uses the key that defines the color that way, then there might be problems? Possible, but if this is really the case then one should be much more worried about local color definitions like `myblue`.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel: apologies for unaccepting this answer, as Symbol 1's answer is what I was hoping for. Thanks for your answer, though: it's been helpful!

Comment: I am upvoting this answer to compensate your loss.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks! But I actually do not care so much about reputation points, I prefer nuts. Organic nuts, of course. ;-)